Derivation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n} = \ln 2$
While playing around with Euler's log-sine integral, I stumbled across the lovely formula
$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2n}\ \frac{1}{2^{2n}}\ \binom{2n}{n} = \ln 2$$
I came to it by accident, so its "derivation" would be dreadfully convoluted. I've never seen this formula before, and wondered if anyone knew of a direct proof of the result.

Mathematica suggests the following generalization, with $x\to 1^-$ giving the case above: $$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2n}\ \frac{x^n}{2^{2n}} \binom{2n}{n} = \ln 2-\ln\Big(1+\sqrt{1-x}\Big)$$

@Semiclassical aha - it is indeed now obvious why the binomial coefficients come into play. I wonder however if there is a "natural" derivation that does not involve starting from the answer

The central binomial coefficients have the generating function $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\dbinom{2n}{n}x^n.$ I suspect that can be derived via more natural methods, but it's been a while since I took combinatorics. From that series, I think we can easily derive the series you are looking for.

If one denotes my sum above as $f(x)$, then one can show that $1+\frac{d}{dx}  f(x^2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. This is at least formally enough to prove the identity, but is not sufficiently satisfying for me to write it up. Looking around, the following AoPS comment includes a proof along the lines I had in mind: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1524777p9164114

Inspired by the comments below the question: Start with the binomial series
$$
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-1/2}{n}(-x)^n
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} \frac{x^n}{4^n} \\
= 1 + x \sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} \frac{x^{n-1}}{4^n}
$$
for $|x| < 1$. Rearrange this to
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} \frac{x^{n-1}}{4^n}
= \frac 1x \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} - 1\right)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}(1+\sqrt{1-x})} \, .
$$
The right-hand side can be written as $2f'(x)/f(x)$ with $f(x) = 1+\sqrt{1-x}$, therefore integration over an interval $[0, x]$ and division by $2$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2n}\binom{2n}{n} \frac{x^{n}}{4^n}
= \bigl . \ln(f(t)) \bigr|_{t=0}^{t=x} = \ln 2 + \ln(1 + \sqrt{1-x}) \, .
$$
(Originally I cheated and used WolframAlpha.)
By Abel's theorem we can take the limit $x\to 1^-$ by setting $x=1$ in the power series, this gives the desired result
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2n}\binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^n} = \ln 2 \, .
$$

@Semiclassical I think you can derive the expression for $f(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n}x^n$ by squaring both sides, and using the identity $\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k} = 4^n$, which likely has a combinatorial proof.

@JimmyK4542 That does look Vandermonde-ish.
